# Camera with no functionalities

Tags: cordova, camera, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to develop an Ionic2 app with a camera interaction. But for this app I only need the camera view, without taking a picture, auto-focus, choose front or back camera... Only the camera.

I'm using the Cordova plugin from Ionic doc:

```
takePicture(){
    Camera.getPicture({
      //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      destinationType: 2,
      quality: 100,
      //sourceType: 2,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      correctOrientation: true,
      encodingType: 1,
      allowEdit: false,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

But I couldn't find something that able to remove this resources. This anyone knows any method or custom plugin that allow this?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this plugin?

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

there is a sample app also

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview-sample-app

Comment: I tried but I didn't get what I expected, but I found an AR plugin that is working well at the moment.